# Given a segment (geometry), check if it intersects with another segment in a set of segments

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I have a set of several geometric segments, they can be defined with two points (for example a segment could be (4,6)--(2,7)).

Now, I want to query this set with another segment, and I want the operation to return whether it intersects with any of them or not. (And as a bonus, to return the instance or pointer to that segment).

The algorithm must be in O(1) or O(logn). Algorithms with preprocessing and/or redundant data structures are also welcome. Algorithms that solve a more specific problem (such as a constraint in segment length) are also welcome.

Example:

segment set:
(4,6)--(2,7)
(5,0)--(5,20)

Query:
(4,5)--(6,5)

Returns:
Intersects with (4,6)--(2,7) at point (5,5)

**My idea:**

I've had several ideas but one of them is to limit the segment length, and therefore do some kind of binary search to a previously sorted point set, so I can find a range of points that I can iterate and try every one of those segments. Since the segments are short, and since I could find an approximate range, the complexity doesn't go all over the place (unless there are too many segments in that same spot!, but that should also be another constraint)

Comment: When you say you allow preprocessing, does it allow to preprocess the queries? (i.e. is the problem offline or online?)

Comment: You can probably solve this with a sweep line algorithm, similar to the ideas in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm, http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~pless/546/lectures/l4.html.  You'll need to make some modest adaptions but I think the same ideas will work here.